# Need help dismissing email composer screen in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an app that allows the user to send a test email from their iPhone.  My app calls a method to activate the compose mail function like this:

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{

    //set up a way to cancel the email here
    //picker is an instance of MSMailComposeViewController already declared in the .h file

    [picker setSubject:@"Test Mail"];

    // Set up recipients

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Icon" ofType:@"png"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Icon"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = @"This is a test mail.";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"mail is working");

}


- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    emailLabel.hidden = NO;
    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            emailLabel.text = @"Mail sending canceled.";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            emailLabel.text = @"Mail saved.";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            emailLabel.text = @"Mail sent.";
            NSLog(@"It's away!");


            UIAlertView *emailAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sent!" message:@"Mail sent successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [emailAlertView show];
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


        }
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {
            emailLabel.text = @"Mail sending failed.";


        }
            break;
        default:
        {
            emailLabel.text = @"Mail not sent.";

        }
        break;
    }

}
```

My problem is that when the compose email function is active, I am unable to come out of this function and return to my app.  The only way out of this is by actually going ahead and sending a message.  There is a default "cancel" bar button that appears on the top left hand corner of the navigation bar, which when clicked, gives me three options:  "delete draft", "save draft", and "cancel".  If I select "delete draft", it does nothing except to return me to the compose message screen.  Is there a way for me to allow the user to return to the app after starting the compose mail function, but prior to sending it?  Is there a way to add extra functionality to the "cancel" bar button to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` with the `- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result` method.

You will dismiss your message view in this method.

EDIT : i confused with `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` but the purpose is the same as with `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  I have edited my question to include this method that I have already in place.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you exactly want to do. If you want to perform some action on cancelling (including dissmiss the view), just include code in your `MFMailComposeResultCancelled` case statement.

Comment: Thanks Yaman.  I just figured it out thanks to your suggestion.  I added the line [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; in the method you mentioned, and it is now working as I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your own code in your `...didFinishWithResult:` method:

```
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        emailLabel.text = @"Mail sending canceled.";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        emailLabel.text = @"Mail saved.";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
    {
        emailLabel.text = @"Mail sent.";
        NSLog(@"It's away!");


        UIAlertView *emailAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sent!" message:@"Mail sent successfully." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [emailAlertView show];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


    }
```

When the result is `MFMailComposeResultSent` you're dismissing the modal view controller and popping the nav stack, which causes the mail compose view controller to go away, and also pops the stack to remove the view controller that presented the compose view controller. When the result is `MFMailComposeResultCancelled`, however, you just set some label's text. Same for `MFMailComposeResultSaved`. You need to dismiss the message compose view controller for these cases too if you want the compose view controller to go away when the user cancels or saves.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this method in your view controller

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

hope this one helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

Set Delegate of MFMailComposeViewController
MFMailComposeViewController *mailcomposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

mailcomposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

And Use this Delegate Method
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error